# How can I find out if my Nokia phone's BL-5C battery is one of the forty million batteries recalled in 2007?

Tags: archive.org

I have an old Nokia cellphone which contains a Nokia BL-5C battery.

Nokia recalled forty million BL-5C batteries in 2007. They created a battery-checker web app that would tell you if your battery was recalled or not. But this web app was taken off the Web in 2011.

Is there any way I can still check my battery online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a Web-archiving service called the Wayback Machine, you can still check your battery online.

1. Shut off your mobile phone.
2. Remove the battery.
3. Flip the battery over, so that you can see its back.
4. Visit: http://web.archive.org/web/batteryreplacement.nokia.com/batteryreplacement/en/
5. Follow the instructions there. Make sure to enter the identification number correctly. Do not confuse the letters "O" and "I" with the numbers "0" and "1". If you make a mistake, the web app may falsely tell you that your battery is fine.
6. Click "Submit".

Your web browser will run [a script](http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/p/6602/127911.aspx) written in JavaScript which will analyze the identification number you have entered.

- If you're sent to a webpage that says, "Your battery is not among those manufactured by Matsushita between December 2005 and November 2006 and your battery will not be replaced", then either:

  - your battery was not recalled, or
  - you entered the number incorrectly.
- If the web app instead tries to send you to http://web.archive.org/web/20111028212742/http://batteryreplacement.nokia.com/batteryreplacement/en/rcr1.1/ (a webpage which will fail to load) then your battery was probably recalled. Phone up Nokia. I believe they will mail you a free replacement battery, plus a prepaid mailer you use to send back the recalled battery.

The Wayback Machine is run by a non-profit organization. If you'd like, you can [donate](http://archive.org/donate/) money or BitCoins to them.